# Run once inside update loop inside a update loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, sprite-kit

So, basically I am making a game that includes land mines, which I want to have them release a red shockwave whenever the player gets close. The only problem is since the code looks like this:

```
loop {
    if (<...Player inside radius...>) {

    spawnShockwave();

    }
}
//This is simplified
```

Each time the player gets near one of the mines, an large number of shockwave images get created (Once every time the loop is run.) How can I get it so that only shockwave gets created per mine.

The game is being written in SpriteKit, and the mines are there own class , however, I have to enumerate each object as an SKNode. Which sucks because that means I can't use custom properties that an SKNode doesn't have.

If anyone has a solution please help.

(Application written in swift)

Comment: An idea: add an `isExploded` property to your landmine object to detect if it has been detonated?

Comment: Yeah it didn't work, it would if the landmine object type were being enumerated however, spritekit is enumerating SKNodes

Comment: You can make your mine a subclass of SKNode if that helps. It isn't clear what your question is however.

Comment: even better idea,  do not use a loop,  user SKPhysicsBody as a radius, on did begin contact, spawn wave

Comment: Could you assign each mine an id, keep track of which ids have been exploded, and check whether that id has been exploded before exploding it again?

Comment: I tried that and It seems like each SKNode is only emitting the shockwave once for each object, however, each node's shockwave position are not directly on that node. For example, mine # 3, 4 and 5's shockwaves are all being emitted from the position of mine # 2